# Maximum $n$ to meet $a_n^2 < 4a_0^2$ when $a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

When $$a_0=\alpha\quad is\quad an\quad integer,\quad and\quad a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}$$,
what's the maximum integer n to meet: $$a_n^2 < 4\alpha^2$$ ? (I guess as a function of $\alpha$, as the maximum $n$ becomes infinite when $\alpha$ goes infinite.)

The lower and upper approximations are known as below as answers to previous questions to this question. (See the post 1540572 for the previous question.)
$$\alpha^2+2n<a_n^2<\alpha^2+2n+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{2}ln\left ( \frac{2n}{\alpha^2}+1 \right )$$

And also this condition was given:
$$e^3 > 16$$
I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this for? Where did you get the problem(s)?

Comment: This was one of interview questions for entrance into the top University in South Korea a few years back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lower and an upper bound for $a_n^2$ that are very close together. Find the largest n where the lower bound for $a_n^2$ is not too high. Calculate the upper bound for that n. If it is also not too high then you are lucky and found the largest n. If the upper bound is too high, you are out of luck.

Someone else might find a use for $e^3 > 16$. Maybe you have to handle small a separately.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. From the lower bound, I got $n=\frac{3\alpha^2}{2}$, and applied it to the upper bound, and $ln(4)$ showed up during its calculation that I could replace with $<\frac32$.